# How to capture the details of the tables that are created and deleted on daily basis in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to find out the list of the tables that are created and deleted daily.

Comment: Store sys.tables daily and compare. Deleted table not store in system objects

Comment: You need to have a look at [CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

First, oldschool and not safe approach. Server level DDL trigger:
[link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)

My recommended solution is to use SQL Server audits:
[image]

Then you able to view all schema changes by using built-in view:
[image]

**Or, more flexible way**, you can query for example last log file and apply any filter by your needs:

```
 declare
 @database_name sysname =   N'my_database'
,@object_name   sysname =   N'my_object_name';

--  get last audit file path/name
declare @last_log_file  nvarchar(512)   =  (select [audit_file_path] from [sys].[dm_server_audit_status]);
declare @dt_from        datetime;
declare @dt_to          datetime;

--  transfer last log file into temporary table 
if object_id('tempdb..#auditlogs', 'u') is not null
begin
    drop table [#auditlogs];
end;


select * into [#auditlogs] from [sys].[fn_get_audit_file](@last_log_file, default, default);

--  get log file first/last rec dates
select 
     @dt_from   =   min([event_time])
    ,@dt_to     =   max([event_time])
from
    [#auditlogs];

--  index temporary table   
create nonclustered index [ix_#auditlogs__event_time]           on [#auditlogs]([event_time]        asc);
create nonclustered index [ix_#auditlogs__database_name]        on [#auditlogs]([database_name]     asc);
create nonclustered index [ix_#auditlogs__object_name]          on [#auditlogs]([object_name]       asc); 
create nonclustered index [ix_#auditlogs__audit_file_offset]    on [#auditlogs]([audit_file_offset] asc); 


--  display some info about the retrieved logs
select 
     [logs_from]        =   @dt_from    
    ,[logs_to]          =   @dt_to
    ,[log_file_name]    =   @last_log_file;

--  remove not actual data
delete from [#auditlogs] where 
        (nullif([database_name] , space(0)) is not null and [database_name] <> @database_name)
    or  (nullif([object_name]   , space(0)) is not null and [object_name]   <> @object_name);


--  get last audit file logs
select  
     [event_time]       =   [l].[event_time]                                    
    ,[user]             =   [l].[session_server_principal_name] + quotename([l].[server_principal_name], '(')       
    ,[action_id]        =   case [l].[action_id] 
                                when 'al'   then    'alter' 
                                when 'dr'   then    'drop' 
                                when 'cr'   then    'create' 
                                else                [l].[action_id] 
                            end                 
    ,[class_type]       =   case [l].[class_type] 
                                when 'u'    then    'table' 
                                when 'if'   then    'inline function' 
                                when 'p'    then    'procedure' 
                                when 'tr'   then    'trigger'   
                                when 'tf'   then    'table valued function' 
                                else                [l].[class_type] 
                            end                         
    ,[server_name]      =   quotename(nullif([l].[server_instance_name] , space(0)))                    
    ,[database_name]    =   quotename(nullif([l].[database_name]        , space(0)))                    
    ,[schema_name]      =   quotename(nullif([l].[schema_name]          , space(0)))                
    ,[object_name]      =   quotename(nullif([l].[object_name]          , space(0)))                
    ,[statement]        =   convert(xml, [st].[statement]).[query]('statement/text()')
from
    [#auditlogs]    as  [l]
outer apply
    (
        select [statement] = (select [statement] from [#auditlogs] where [audit_file_offset] = [l].[audit_file_offset] and [event_time] = [l].[event_time] order by [sequence_number] asc for xml path (''))
    )               as  [st]
group by
        [l].[audit_file_offset]
    ,[l].[event_time]                                   
    ,[l].[session_server_principal_name]
    ,[l].[server_principal_name]
    ,[l].[action_id]    
    ,[l].[class_type]
    ,[l].[server_instance_name] 
    ,[l].[database_name]        
    ,[l].[schema_name]          
    ,[l].[object_name]  
    ,[st].[statement]   
order by 
        [l].[event_time]    desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM sys.tables
 WHERE create_date >= '20180712' AND create_date < '20180713'
```

or if you want a particular date :

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE cast(create_date AS DATE) = '2018-07-13'
```